# Error aumentar stock

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Tengo un codigo para aumentar stock en mi aplicacion pero no esta realizando si desminuye el stock y ya copie el codigo de disminuir pero ahora cambiando el signo para que aumentara  el stock

```
[aumentar_stock]
  @idproducto as integer,
  @cantidad as decimal(18,2)
  as
  update producto set stock=stock+@cantidad where idproducto=@idproducto
```

el siguiente codigo es para aumnetar que es el que esta funcionando actualmente

```
[disminuir_stock]
@idproducto as integer,
@cantidad as decimal(18,2)
as
update producto set stock=stock-@cantidad where idproducto=@idproducto
```

el siguente es el comando que estoy usando en visual basic el aumentar stock no lo se porque cuando disminuir stock si funciona

```
    Public Function aumentar_stock(ByVal dts As vdetalle_venta) As Boolean
    Try
        conectar()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("aumentar_stock")


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Connection = cnn


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idproducto", dts.gidproducto)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", dts.gcantidad)



        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    Finally
        desconectar()
    End Try
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con no funciona? ¿Estás seguro de que estás enviando los valores correctos? ¿Hay algún mensaje de error?

Comment: no me muestra ningun error, tengo un producto con un stock de 200 productos y agrego el producto guardo y me elimina del stock el producto, y cuando elimino la venta deberia actualizar la tabla de producto